# Database running out of space

Tags: sql-server, database, diskspace

My database has 16MB of space left

I used to just truncate as I was taught but I found these links that advise against truncating

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/19/sql-server-shrinking-database-is-bad-increases-fragmentation-reduces-performance/

Is there anything else I can do on my database to reduce the size other then deleting table records? Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should most definitely look for ways to increase storage space as a long term solution. Having only 15MB left in database can easily lead to corruption and database going offline.

If you’re on SQL Server 2008+ you can try to enable its native [data compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx).